# Solution to splitting array into equal subarrays too slow

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic-programming

I'm having trouble with a dynamic programming problem. I have tested my solution against test cases, and it is correct. However, it is too slow. This leads me to believe that I may not be caching the solutions to subproblems effectively. Here is the problem statement:

*There is an array A that contains N numbers. Given an array, a player can split the array into two non-empty subarrays only if the elements in each subarray sum to the same value. After a split is made, the player discards one subarray and is allowed to continue splitting on the remaining subarray. This continues until a split is no longer possible. What is the maximum number of splits possible on the given array A?*

Here is my (slow) solution, which calls topSplit(A) on the given array:

```
def topSplitAux(A, C, i, j):

    if -1 != C[i][j]:
        return C[i][j]

    if i == j:
        return 0

    s = float('-inf')
    for k in range(i + 1, j): 
        if sum(A[i:k]) == sum(A[k:j]):
            p1 = 1 + topSplitAux(A, C, i, k)
            p2 = 1 + topSplitAux(A, C, k, j)
            s = max(s, p1, p2)
            C[i][j] = s 
    if s == float('-inf'):    # we couldn't split, game over 
        C[i][j] = 0
    return C[i][j]

def topSplit(A):

    # initialize a cache to store solutions already solved 
    n = len(A)
    # the subproblem we are interested in will be in C[0][n]
    C = [[-1 for _ in range(n + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]

    return topSplitAux(A, C, 0, n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    T = int(raw_input())
    for t in range(T):
        N = int(raw_input())
        A = map(int, raw_input().split())
        n = len(A)
        print topSplit(A)
```

Here's a simple test case:

```
3
3
3 3 3
4
2 2 2 2
7
4 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

with expected result:

```
0
2
3
```

Any help on making this solution faster would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you're running with _Python 2.X_ you could start by replacing `range` with `xrange`.

Comment: Could you give us some of your test cases to check it out ?

Comment: Edited the post to contain a test case. I have longer ones but they're too large to post on paste bin and I'm not sure how to convey that information to you.